# A 10x10 table filled with 0 to 9 numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I saw this question but I couldn't find the answer.
Assume that we have a 10x10 table, and it's filled with 0 to 9 numbers ( 10 of each of them are in the table, 10x zero, 10x one, and ... )

**By using graph**, prove that we have a column or a row that we can find at least 4 different numbers in it.

edit: I have found this method to create a graph from any table-matrix :
https://www.math3ma.com/blog/matrices-probability-graphs

after that, I thought that it would be a good way to use coloured edges.
and now the thing to prove is to have a vertex with at least four colour edges connected to it. maybe with pigeonhole, the problem can be solved but I couldn't

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each number $i$ from $0$ to $9$ let $r_i$ and $c_i$ be the number of rows and columns, respectively, containing the number $i$. Since all ten instances of $i$ are contained in a table with dimensions $r_i$ and $c_i$, we have $r_i\times c_i\ge 10$. It easily follows $r_i+c_i\ge 7$. It follows $\sum_i r_i+c_i\ge 70$. Wthout loss of generality we can suppose that $\sum  r_i\ge 35$. The pigeonhole  principle implies that there exists a row which is counted in at least four $r_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your neat and simple proof. But the question asks us to prove the term by using the graph theory.

Comment: @III_phr I was started from a graph interpretation of the question (We have a coloring of edges of a complete directed graph with $10$ vertices into colors from $0$ to $9$. For each $i$ let $r_i$ (resp. $c_i$) be the number of vertices which have an incoming (resp. outgoing) edge of color $i$. Show that there exists a vertex incident to edges of four distinct colors). But then, dealing with the adjacency matrix, I saw this solution. It turned out that the solution can be more simply presented without graph interperetation, so I skipped it as non-needed.

Comment: Oh, your right, it's a simpler way of presentation of your way.
and to be considered, I think that just implementing the question by graph and then solving it is enough, and there is no need to use special graph theorems. Thanks again!