# A table with numbers 0 to 9

Tags: discrete-mathematics

consider a table which is filled with numbers from 0 to 9
and each number is repeated exactly 10 times
using graph prove that there exists a row or column with more than 3 unique digits
I faced this question and couldn't solve it using graph
I'll be glad if you help me solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A 10x10 table filled with 0 to 9 numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733771/a-10x10-table-filled-with-0-to-9-numbers)

Comment: @K.defaoite, that question looks related, but the question here allows for a more general $m\times n$ array, with $mn=100$.